# Convert a Cocoa Touch latitude/longitude to a string without degree symbol

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsstring, latitude-longitude, cllocation

I'm trying to convert `CLLocation` latitude / longitude to a string.  I can successfully do this with the follow code:

```
// extract latitude from CLLocation object and cast to string
NSString *latitude = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g°", location.coordinate.latitude];
```

this gives me a value like: 34.10111º.  I would like this number as a pure string without the º degree symbol.

Should I init the string with a different format?

I tried initing with the format @"%d" and the string comes out to a different number altogether.

Comment: Talk about a WTF moment.  Bahahahahahahaha! Too funny.

Comment: "asked Apr 1". Happy fool's day :))

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have a degree symbol in your format string. Remove it and you should be fine.

As to the other part of your question, `%d` as a format specifier wants an integer, and you're giving it a floating-point number. Your `%g` is correct, as would be `%e` or `%f`.

Comment: That's definitely it! Thanks a million!